# Check if an object has loaded data or alternative text with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an object on my page, and I'm trying to check if the data has been loaded or not.

```
<object id ='pdf_support_checker' data="/dummy.pdf"><p>Testing</p></object>
```

I've tried the load() function, but it still evaluates to true.  Can't find anything in the html when the alt text is displayed either.

Either Javascript or jquery is fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Got it!  I used [this plugin](https://github.com/teamdf/jquery-visible/) in my script.

html:

```
  <object id ='pdf_support_checker' data="/dummys.pdf">
       <span id ='pdf_text'>Testing</span>        
  </object>
```

css:

```
#pdf_support_checker {
 background: #fff;
 height: 0px;
}
span#pdf_text {
color: #fff;
}
```

javascript:

```
window.pdfSupport = 1;
if ($('#pdf_text').visible(true, true)) {
     window.pdfSupport = 0;
};
```